# play audio file over VoIP

Tags: audio, voip

I want to implement a simple VoIP system which can achieve following;

1. The user uploads a mp3 or wav file and gives a phone number.
2. the given phone number is dialed, when the phone is picked, the uploaded mp3/wav file is played. once the whole file is played, the call is hung up.

i want to know if there is any opensource library which supports this?? or an opensource software using which i can achieve this?

Comment: What platform, OS, etc ?

Comment: Is there also a simple way to play an mp3/ogg/wav to answer incoming calls?

Answer (score 2):

I do similar testing as this for my job.

I have

1. a test framework on my box in my office using Freeswitch and I've created some users with passwords on the FreeSWITCH box.
2. Then I use a sip testing tool / client to manage the connection to the sip proxy, to another user.

For example... say my freeswitch is ip: 120.0.0.7

I am registering on that freeswitch as user 5000 and i want to call user 4000 who is also registered.

I use either **SIPP (linux)** or **SIPCLI (windows.)**

**SIPP**

The benefits of SIPP is that it's truly robust and can do a myriad of performance testing, and what not.  But ot send audio it's a bit challenging, but it's doable. you're basically sending pcap's of recorded audio in some codec (g711, g729, etc.)  so you run a command like:

```
sudo sipp -s [the phone number/ user] [your freeswitch] -sn uac_pcap -mi [your ip] -l 1 -m 1
```

The last two parameters (l and m) set how much load, by default sipp will send 10calls per sec. you prob dont want that.  so l says "limit the calls to #" and m says "only run x calls at a time."

**SIPCLI**

The much easier method is sipcli (but it's a windows only tool.)
In sipcli, you basically can send a wav file, as well as text to speech.  I love it.  it has a built in library that will dial the number and you could pass something like -t "This is a test of the test harness for sip and v o i p testing." it would convert that to audio on the call, on the fly.  you can also build out scenarios that point to wav files you've recorded....

SIPCLI would use a command like SIPP to connect:

```
sipcli [user/phone number] -d [domain or proxy] -t "This is text i want converted to speech on the phone call"
```

you could also pass in a link to a wav.

sipcli can also send dtmf tones, or you could point to wav's of dtmf tones.

the scenario editor is a bit complex at first, and takes a bit of getting used to. But once you get the hang of making scenario files, it's pretty easy.

**Benefits of SIPP**

SIPP can capture performance metrics (the over all time in ms between your configured start and end point)
SIPP can drive thousands of calls at your desired end
SIPP can ramp up calls or ramp them down on the fly
SIPP can generate statisics and csv files for analysis
SIPP scenarios you write are building the packets themselves. So you have more control over what your packet sends on the INVITE.
SIPP is open source

**Negatives of SIPP**

SIPP can NOT send a wav file
SIPP can NOT generate it's own dtmf tones (it uses pcaps, which can be problematic)
SIPP can NOT generate text to speech
SIPP is somewhat complicated to get going

**Benefits of SIPCLI**

SIPCLI can convert text to speech on the fly
SIPCLI can use recorded wav's to send to the recipient
SIPCLI is easy to use
SIPCLI can also act as a reciever (i.e. an IVR playing a greeting and taking input)
SIPCLI has some logic to validate data received (like user pressed #3, then #4.)

**Negatives of SIPCLI**

SIPCLI doesn't let you have access to the SIP headers it sends (so less control over the test)
SIPCLI doesn't do load or performance metrics
SIPCLI's editor is kinda difficult at first, but it's not as hard as learning SIPP's advanced features
SIPCLI is NOT opensource.... it's trial is 90% useful. To get the other 10% (longer phone calls) you need to purchase it at $70.

I've also tried other tools like PJSua, but these two are my bread and butter for testing the scenarios you are talking about.

Regarding the Framework/softwsitch/proxy... I use Freeswitch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use Asterisk, Freeswitch ( My personal preference) Or a number of other platforms similar to this.

Once you have freeswitch setup, check out this link to get it going:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Javascript_QuickStart

Comment: Ah I just read your message more closely. My solution is based on the user calling freeswitch. In your case, take a look at : http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_commands#originate

Answer (score 0):

use [ivrworx](http://code.google.com/p/altalena/) for simple testing

see streamer example.